# Android rotate pixel in bitmap but the bitmap is turn to white/mising

Tags: java, android, bitmap

I have a fingerprint image as a bitmap and then i rotate the pixel with this code :

```
public Bitmap rotateImage(Bitmap rotateBmp)
{
        double radians=Math.toRadians(90);
        double cos, sin;
        cos=Math.cos(radians);
        sin=Math.sin(radians);
        boolean rotatePix[][]=new boolean[width][height];

        for(int i=0;i<width;++i)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<height;++j)
            {
                int centerX=core.x, centerY=core.y;
                int m=i - centerX;
                int n=j - centerY;
                int k=(int)(m * cos + n * sin);
                int l=(int)(n * cos - m * sin);

                k+=centerX;
                l+=centerY;



                if(!((k<0)||(k>width-1)||(k<0)||(k>height-1)))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        rotatePix[k][l]=binaryMap[i][j];
                    }
                    catch(Exception e)
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        for(int i=0;i<width;++i)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<height;++j)
            {
                if(rotatePix[i][j]==true)
                {
                    rotateBmp.setPixel(i, j, Color.BLACK);
                }
                else
                {
                    rotateBmp.setPixel(i, j, Color.WHITE);
                }
            }
        }

        return rotateBmp;
    //}
}
```

but then when I check the result, the black pixel become less then before, I guess it turns to white because when I check the calculation in the X and Y coordinate, many of them has same X and Y new coordinate and maybe it change the black pixel to white. Please tell me how to rotate the pixel in an angle but with same color with before. I attach the result here for you to look. Many thanks for your help...

[image: Rotate Result]

Comment: if you cannot see the image, please open it here : http://s22.postimg.org/fffg5ym5d/Screenshot_2015_02_06_09_53_10.png

Comment: The issue with above code is that, when image is transformed, x-y pixels maps to new positions that are not integers and code rounds them to smallest integer value, as suggested in the answers, you are better to use Android's rotation which computes a weighted value for each pixel in the output image.

Answer (score 1):

If what you want to do is just rotate the bitmap, you could use a `Matrix` like I have done below:

```
public Bitmap rotateBitmap (Bitmap rotateBmp) {
    int rotationDegree = 90;

    /* rotate the image based the rotation degree */
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.postRotate(rotationDegree);

    rotateBmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(rotateBmp, 0, 0, rotateBmp.getWidth(),
            rotateBmp.getHeight(), matrix, true);

    // rotateBmp is now rotated by 90 degrees
    return rotateBmp;
}
```

I hope this helps.